# How to filter rows where there is a trailing whitespace in a certain field?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

How can I filter records from file where there is a trailing whitespace in a certain field? E.g if I have a file containing rows like these (| as a field delimiter):

```
a232|var1|var2
a342 |var1|var2
a234|var1|var2
```

filtering should return a row

```
a342 |var1|var2
```

I do not want to remove these white spaces. I tried this:

```
awk '$1 ~ /[\s]+$/' myfile.txt
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your line is almost correct, but you need to define the `FS` if it is not `space`, in your case it is `pipe`:

```
awk -F\| '$1~/[[:space:]]+$/'
```

you can change the `$1` to `$x` to filter on "certain" field.

test:

```
kent$  echo "a232|var1|var2
a342 |var1|var2
a234|var1|var2"|awk -F\| '$1~/[[:space:]]+$/'
a342 |var1|var2
```

Comment: @IgorChubin yes I did.

Comment: +1 works perfectly for me, was just about to post the exact same thing

Comment: @Kent - maybe also explain why the `[]` had to be dropped around `\s`

Comment: Differing `awk` versions? Try `awk -F\| '$1~/[[:space:]]+$/'`?

Comment: Thanks @grebneke! This is solution I was looking for.

Comment: @jrara I pointed out the problem in your command, the `FS`. if my line doesn't work with your awk version, the problem might be the regex flavor. `\s` should be supported by ERE. if you had gnu awk, use that one. otherwise, try grebneke's regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `grep`:

```
grep '^[^|]* |'
```

Comment: if the "certain field" is the 1st, last, etc it is ok to use grep. however think about if there are 15columns and OP wants to filter based on 7th. in this case, awk is a good direction.

Comment: This works with my example data, thanks! It would be nice to determine the column (as @Kent said), so that is why I tried to use awk for this.

Comment: `awk` should be the right choice since you want a specific column

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
sed -n 's/\(.*\) |.*/\n&/p'
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to find all the white spaces in my data fields.

Comment: why trailing .* after | ? last field could have space without trigger the filter ?

Answer (score 0):

Use grep like this:

```
grep " |" yourfile
```

or, more generally

```
grep "\s|" yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example,

```
a232|var1|var2
a342 |var1|var2
a234|var1|var2
```

Try this,

```
sed -n 2p filename
```

here, `2p` indicates that you are filtering second row from the file.

if you want to filter third line then code will look like this,

```
sed -n 3p filename
```

In general we can state, `sed -n Np filename`

here, `N` stand for index of line which you want to filter from a given file.

Comment: filtering is not about the line number but line content so sed -n '2p' is giving the 2nd line even or not this have to be filtered.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Note you can format your answer with the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/\(.*\)[[:blank:]]\|/ p' YourFile
```

`--posix` for GNU sed